# Accessing data in another column in Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using Datatables and I'm trying to access data in another column. It's unclear to me if I should be using [columns.data](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data) or if I should be taking another approach by using getting the column index instead?

## Objective

- In the second render function, I want the first `makeSlug(data)` to be referencing the `"data": "district"` and the second one to remain the same and reference `"data": "school"`

### scripts.js

```
"columns": [
{ "data": "district",
    "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
        return '<a href="/schools/' + makeSlug(data) + '">' + data + '</a>';
    }
},
{ "data": "school",
    "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
        return '<a href="/schools/' + makeSlug(data) + '/' + makeSlug(data) + '">' + data + '</a>';
    }
},
{ "data": "subject"},
{ "data": "rate"},
{ "data": "test_takers"}
],
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Third argument `row` is an array containing full data set for the row. Use `row['district']` to access `district` property.

For example:

```js
{ 
   "data": "school",
   "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
        return '<a href="/schools/' + makeSlug(row['district']) + '/' + makeSlug(data) + '">' + data + '</a>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Worked like a charm.